# How two java object HashCode can be similar

Tags: java

In below code i have two string object both are different object but i am getting the similar hashcode. how it's possible.

public class ObjectHashCode {

```
    public static void main(String...mj){

            String str1 = new String("Aa");
            String str2 = new String("BB");

            System.out.println(str1.hashCode());//2112
            System.out.println(str2.hashCode());//2112
        }
```

}

Comment: There are 2^32 possible unique hash codes. There are many more possible Strings. Hence different Strings can have the same hashCode.

Comment: That's what they call 'em "hash collisions", and it's one of the reasons why Hash*** have buckets or some super complex shifting logic. Either for hash-value-collisions or hash-value-modulo-collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always read the documentation regarding the fundamental contract between the method input and the method output. In this case the documentation states (omitting irrelevant paragraphs):

> It is **not** required that if two objects are unequal
>   according to the {@link java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)}
>   method, then calling the {@code hashCode} method on each of the
>   two objects must produce distinct integer results.  However, the
>   programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results
>   for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

As for why the values are the same, the nice thing about Java is you can always have a look at the source. This is how `hashCode` is computed for an instance of `String`.

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Now take your example String values:

```
"Aa" = 31 * (31 * 0 + 65) + 97 = 2112
"BB" = 31 * (31 * 0 + 66) + 66 = 2112
```

**Note**: a numeric value for `'A' = 65, 'B' = 66, 'a' = 97`.